# What are precompiled in moonbeam and relevant EVM enabled chains?

Tags: evm, moonbeam, ethereum

What are precompiled in moonbeam and relevant EVM-enabled chains? and why we should use it if we are going to create EVM enabled chain?

Comment: Have you checked the Moonbeam docs on precompiles? See: https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/build/canonical-contracts/precompiles/

Comment: If you want to have EVM enabled chain which is Ethereum compatible, you need to support precompiles which are present on Ethereum. There are 8 handy precompiles on Eth which you can use in your smart contract and all of them are included in the Frontier
https://github.com/paritytech/frontier